# Get height of Displacement Texture

Tags: texturing, materials, image, displacement

I import a displacement image as Image Texture node for my Plane. Like it is done here at the bottom of the site: https://help.ambientcg.com/02-Using%20the%20assets/Using_PBR_maps_in_Blender.html
Now i have the problem that the texture of my Plane goes through an other object. So I thought about moving the Plane down, with the value of the height of this plane. But it figured out that its not that easy to get the value of this height of the texture Displacement of this plane. Now my Question is, how can I get this height? like the min and max values of this displacement image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you realized, the problem with the *Microdisplacement* feature is that it doesn't generate a real displaced mesh which has dimensions. But when you are using a greyscale height map and use it on the plane, there is a way to guess or more or less accurate calculate the height.

The greyscale values usually range from black (0) to white (1). In my example, I have a heightmap of a mountain where the darkest part is 0.0 and the brightest (highest) part is around 0.3 (it's not going all the way up to 1).

If you now have a plane with a scale of 1/1/1 and plug the height map into a *Displacement* node and leave it at the default values (*Midlevel* 0.500 and *Scale* 1.000), the lowest part will be at -0.5 meters (below the original plane) and the heighest part will be at -0.2 meters, which makes a height of 0.3 meters.

So, to sum it up: at a scale of 1, the height of the terrain will be the height of the brightest pixel, and the "ground level" will be the original plane minus the midlevel value. If the darkest pixel in your height map is brighter than 0.0, it will be that much above ground level.

This is an example with the *Displacement* node's default settings, the *Midlevel* value is at 0.5 and the *Scale* is at 1:

[image: height default]

And for comparison, the *Midlevel* set to 0.0 and the *Scale* factor set to 2, doubling the height of the terrain:

[image: height scaled]