# Embossed logo on glass surface using displace node looks incorrect

Tags: node-editor, shaders

Im following a tutorial, how to apply a logo on glass surface using a displacement node.
Im running into two issues, the logo letters look too thick bevelled, and in the preview shader it looks correct, but when I switch to render shader, the logo looks shattered. I have attached the Blend file as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The texture is not packed into the blend file.

Comment: In cycles settings of your material change displacement to bump only. The vertices are displaced in real world coordinates and I guess you don't have a high enough density of vertices to make it work.

Comment: Here's the Texture: https://ibb.co/TRp5JqZ

Comment: @Gorgious, the tutorials settings as is: https://ibb.co/1QPGxFT

Comment: If you're going to follow a tutorial, you better do it to the letter :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differences between your model and the one in the tutorial: first of all, he sets the *Strength* in the *Displacement* node to 0.03, yours is at 0.2 - that is almost 7× larger. It also depends on the size of your object, if yours is smaller or larger than the one in the tutorial, you might need to adjust it further.

Then he has *Subdivision Surface* modifier on the object set to *Level* 3 to have more resolution in the mesh for finer details in the displacement (although 3 he has just for the viewport, for render it's only 2). You do not have any subdivision on the mesh.

The other thing which makes the render look odd apart from the too strong displacement, you can see the mirrored logo on the backside of the bottle through the glass, distorted by the IOR. I did not watch the complete tutorial so I don't know if he has excluded the backside from the UV map to not show the mirrored logo or if you just cannot see it that strong from the fact that he has a liquid object inside which is additionally obstructing the view through the bottle. Your scene is missing that liquid.

Comment: Yes I noticed even the slightest values make a big difference in the result. Thank you Gordon!

Comment: @blenderbreath You're welcome! If you want to know more about how displacement scale works, read my answer on this question: [Get Height of Displacement Texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264405/get-height-of-displacement-texture/264409#264409)